# Trait methods are not fully visible in groovy-eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, traits, groovy-eclipse

I have 2 traits:

```
trait LinkTrait<D> {
  String compositeKey
}

trait Named<D> {
  String name
}
```

and a class:

```
class Project implements LinkTrait<Project>, Named<Project> {

  String company

  def beforeValidate() {
    if( company && name ) setCompositeKey company + '_' + name
  }
}
```

The code compiles and executes just fine.

The problem is, that in **Eclipse 2020-03** and

```
Eclipse Groovy Development Tools

Version: 3.8.0.v202004242058-e2003
```

the code looks like:

[image]

Here the `name` field and `setCompositeKey()` method are suggested in code-completion, but are both underlined as unknown and neither `Ctrl+Click` nor `F3` do not open its' declarations.

Is this a bug or some "misconfiguration"?

Comment: New issue created in Groovy-Eclipse: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1113

Comment: Until a fix is available, you can 1) define the traits in the same source file as the implementing class or 2) add interface methods for get and set of each property.  This can help the IDE along and will not negatively impact the compiled class files.

Comment: thanks for reaction. Looking forward to see the fix in release