# Groovy-Eclipse !in Operator marked as error

Tags: eclipse, groovy, groovy-eclipse

Using freshly installed Eclipse:

```
Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
Build id: 20230608-1333
```

and

```
Eclipse Groovy Development Tools    5.0.0.v202306301519-e2306
```

with `Groovy Compiler Version` set to `3.0.18`

the code

```
if( methodNode.code !in BlockStatement ) return false
```

produces an Error marker:
[image]

Needless to say, that the code compiles and runs just fine.

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Created an [issue](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1508)

Comment: Can SO actually help here? IDEs will always be prone to false positives
and therefore you either have to suffer the IDE (e.g. disable this
check) or make the code suffer for your IDE (rewrite the code to be
warn-free).  Or report a bug and sit it out.

Comment: @cfrick hope to see this kind of interaction here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713375/trait-methods-are-not-fully-visible-in-groovy-eclipse ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment in the issue, I added

```
-Dgroovy.antlr4=true
```

to the bottom of my `eclipse.ini` and it solved the problem